# Problems with input to a function that used RapidJson its AddMember function

Tags: c++, c++11, rapidjson

I am trying to write a function that should check whether a member exists on a document. If it does it should remove the member and re-add it with a different value.

This is what I got so far (d is a `rapidjson::Document`):

```
void addMemberWithoutDuplication(std::string member, rapidjson::Value val) {
    if (d.HasMember(member)) {
        d.RemoveMember(member);
    }
    d.AddMember(rapidjson::StringRef(member), val, allocator);
}
```

This compiles and runs however the output is not as expected:
[image]

As shown `rapidjson::StringRef(member)` seems to be the cause of the question marks inside the boxes.

Reading these pages of the docs did not help me a lot:

- https://rapidjson.org/structrapidjson_1_1_generic_string_ref.html
- https://rapidjson.org/classrapidjson_1_1_generic_object.html

From what I read I should be doing it correctly but most likely my inexperience reading these types of docs is an issue here. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or am missing?

Comment: `Ref` in `StringRef` is suspicious when referring to local variable. Try to add this member by deep copy.

Comment: Can you not do `d[member] = val;`?

Comment: @rafix07 could you give me an example in how to do this. I am pretty new to c++ an using the internet I find it hard to get an example using the term "deep copy" in that context.

Comment: Under [this link](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html#TemporaryValues) see section: *Move semantics and temporary values* and examples with `Value` class use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found an answer in this post: https://github.com/Tencent/rapidjson/issues/261

When using a dynamic reference, a copy of the string should be stored in a `rapidjson::Value`.

This makes the code as follows:

```
void addMemberWithoutDuplication(std::string member, rapidjson::Value val) {
    if (d.HasMember(member)) {
        d.RemoveMember(member);
    }
    rapidjson::Value key(member.c_str(), allocator);
    d.AddMember(key, val, allocator);
}
```